# How to enable swipe gesture when tabView is positioned bottom

Tags: nativescript, swipe, gesture, tabview, nativescript-vue

I am using `nativescript-vue` and I wanted to play around with `tab-view`. The problem is, when I set my tabs to be positioned at the bottom of the screen, the swipe gesture no longer works and is somewhat disabled. I want to enable swipe gesture.

Because I'm new to native-script or android, I'm not really sure how to enable it.

```html
<Page actionBarHidden="true">

    <TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">

        <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
            <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
                <Label class="message" :text="msg" col="0" row="0"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </TabViewItem>

        <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
            <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
                <Label class="message" text="Tab 2 Content"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </TabViewItem>

        <TabViewItem title="Tab 3">
            <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
                <Label class="message" text="Tab 3 Content"/>
            </GridLayout>

        </TabViewItem>

    </TabView>

</Page>
```

The above script creates `tabview` with 3 tabs, but the problem is, now you can't swipe between the tabs. If I set `androidTabsPosition="top"`, then swipe gesture works.

Can someone please enlighten me how to enable swipe gestures.

Here's the documentary for tabView in [**nativescript-vue**](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/tab-view/)

Answer (score 2):

Enable swipe on the view pager from the TabView's loaded event. I didn't notice any side effect with this behaviour, incase if you hit anything let me know.

**Template**

```
...
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" @loaded="onTabViewLoaded">
...
```

**JS**

```
       onTabViewLoaded: function(args) {
            if (args.object.android) {
                args.object.android.viewPager.setSwipePageEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```